# How to design adding/subtracting logic circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I am tasked of creating a logic circuit that can switch between adding and subtracting. I can do that part, but how can I indicate whether the result is positive or negative? One of my ideas is to light an LED if on subtraction mode AND if B>A. But how could I check if B>A?

Comment: Do you know how to build a comparator circuit?

Comment: If you simply use 2's-complement to represent numbers in binary, the sign bit is the MSB of each word. The result of an addition/subtraction will have the correct sign automatically.

Comment: Have you searched this site?

Comment: Oh, well. Feel free to examine [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOEG7.png). Everything you need is there, and more.

Comment: Useful reading: https://www.electronicshub.org/binary-adder-and-subtractor/

Comment: Dave, we are required to use 4 bit adders to add/subtract a 5 bit signed number. Also, it says only 1 xor gate must be used and the rest must be done with 8 x 1 multiplexers which I am confused about.